# Zoom in so a marker is visible in LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet

I'm using the **LeafletJS** ( https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html ) and **Leaflet.markerclusterer** ( https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster ) to create a map on my site. I've almost finished work on it, but I can't figure out one last part.

What I do is show a list of the markers in the viewport like so:

[image]

Then if you click on one of them in the bottom row, it will `panTo()` the correct area.

The issue I'm having is that if (as you can see in my example) the link happens to be in a cluster at this level, then you can't see it. How would one force it to zoom.

What I need is a method to zoom in one step at a time, until its visible.

```
window.VARS.markerCluster.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        if (layer.options.linkid == linkid) {

                console.dir(layer);
                window.VARS.Map_Modal.panTo(layer.getLatLng());

        }

});
```

This is some code I used on Google Maps to achieve the same thing, but obvioulsy it doesn't

```
           var zoom = window.VARS.Google_Map_Modal.getZoom();
            window.VARS.Google_Map_Modal.setCenter(window.VARS.markers[e.getAttribute('data-what')].getPosition());
            var zoomInterval = setInterval(function() {
                 if(!window.VARS.markers[e.getAttribute('data-what')].map) {
                     zoom++
                     if (zoom < 15) {
                        window.VARS.Google_Map_Modal.setZoom(zoom++);
                    }
                 } else {
                     clearInterval(zoomInterval);
                 }
            }, 300);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the **Leaflet.markercluster** library, you can trivially use `zoomToShowLayer`, which is a method of a `markerClustersGroup` object. So, to do this, you have to find your variable referencing your `markerCLustersGroup` object which is initialized like so, somewhere in your code:

```
var myMarkerClusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup();
```

Once you have your group, you can invoke the said method like so:

```
myMarkerClustersGroup.zoomToShowLayer(layer);
```

...instead of using `window.VARS.Map_Modal.panTo(layer.getLatLng());`

Here's the documentation for this method from the [official documentation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-group-methods):

**zoomToShowLayer**(layer, callback): Zooms to show the given marker (spiderfying if required), calls the callback when the marker is visible on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so not directly an answer to the original question, but this does what I set out to achieve. Using this extra plugin:

https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable

I was able to disable the clusters at a certain stage (when there would be less markers):

```
        // disable clustering at certain zoom
        if (window.VARS.Map_Modal.getZoom() >= 12) {
            window.VARS.markerCluster.freezeAtZoom();
        } else {
            window.VARS.markerCluster.enableClustering();
        }
```

Then I don't need to zoom in, as they are visible from the current viewport. I'm sure its not a perfect solution, but it should do for what I need.

I'd still be interested to see if anyone has another solution (for someone else in the future)